# Why is addEventListener returning as not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script that is trying to register a click on a button. However, I keep getting the error `*element*.addEventListener` is not a function.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="game">
    <canvas id="gameScreen" width="550" height="500"></canvas>
    <div id="output"><p></p></div>
    <div id="controls">
        <button id="north">North</button>
        <button id="east">East</button>
        <button id="west">West</button>
        <button id="south">South</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var outputText = output.querySelector("p");
    var controls = document.getElementById("controls");
    var directionButtons = controls.getElementsByTagName("button");

    directionButtons.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this);
    })
})
```

**Error**

> TypeError: directionButtons.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: Because you have to iterate through to add click event - `directionButtons` is an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** method will return a list of nodes and you should loop through them and attach listener to every one :

```
function my_click(){
   alert(this.id);
}

var directionButtons = controls.getElementsByTagName("button");

for(i=0; i<directionButtons.length; i++) {
    directionButtons[i].addEventListener("click", my_click, false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function my_click(){
   alert(this.id);
}

var directionButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for(i=0; i<directionButtons.length; i++) {
    directionButtons[i].addEventListener("click", my_click, false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='2'>Button 2</button>
<button id='3'>Button 3</button>
<button id='4'>Button 4</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm apparently not able to think today.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `directionButtons` is an array of multiple elements. You'll need to use loop here in order to add listeners.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var outputText = output.querySelector("p");
  var controls = document.getElementById("controls");
  var directionButtons = controls.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (i = 0; i < directionButtons.length; i++) {
    directionButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <canvas id="gameScreen" width="550" height="500"></canvas>
  <div id="output">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="controls">
    <button id="north">North</button>
    <button id="east">East</button>
    <button id="west">West</button>
    <button id="south">South</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm apparently not able to think today.